Proof that $\left<B,f,\cup \right>$ is a Boolean Algebra
This is from Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Elliot Mendelson.

I understand why $\cup$ is commutative, but I can't figure out how to prove the second condition that $\cup$ is associative. My attempt:
Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be in $B$. Then $(x\cup y)\cup z = (((x^{'}\cap y^{'})^{'})^{'}\cap z^{'})^{'}$.
I think I need to show that $(x^{'})^{'}=x$ for all $x$ in $B$ because then the result would follow from the associativity of $\cap$, but I am not sure how to do that either. If I could show that $x\le (x^{'})^{'}$ and $(x^{'})^{'}\le x$ for all $x$ in $B$, then $(x^{'})^{'}=x$ would follow from antisymmetry of $\le$. Since $(x^{'})^{'}\cap x^{'} = x^{'}\cap (x^{'})^{'} = 0 = z \cap z^{'}$, from condition (3.) it follows that $(x^{'})^{'}\cap x = (x^{'})^{'}$, thus $(x^{'})^{'}\le x$. How do you show that $x\le (x^{'})^{'}$?

You might want to check the paper A first order proof of a theorem of Frink, Padmanabhan, in Algebra Universalis 13 (1981) pages 397-400. If you can't access the paper, I might sort you out with the proof. Also of interest would be the paper of Frink, Representations of Boolean algebras in Bull. AMS 47 (1941), pages 775-776. But this last one uses Stone representation of Boolean algebras, which you might not know about.

You've shown that for all $y$ we have $y\cap y''=y''$, taking $y=x'$ we have $x'''=x'\cap x'''$, therefore:
$$
x\cap x'''=x\cap (x'\cap x''')=(x\cap x')\cap x'''=(x''\cap x''')\cap x'''=x''\cap (x'''\cap x''')=x''\cap x'''
$$
therefore
$$
x\cap x''=x
$$
(note: I've used that for all $z,w$ we have $z\cap z'=w\cap w'$ and $z\cap z=z$)

A shorter version would be $$x \wedge x'''=x\wedge(x'\wedge x'')=(x\wedge x')\wedge x'''=0\wedge x''' =0,$$ whence $x\wedge x''=x$ and $x\leq x''$.
